# construct select query from two tables in zend

Tags: sql, select, join, zend-framework

I'm new to zend 1.12 and I want to construct the following query, please advice:

```
SELECT tbl_user.first_name, tbl_user.last_name, tbl_user.email, tbl_user_group.group_id  
FROM `tbl_user`, `tbl_user_group` 
WHERE `organization_id` = 5 
  AND tbl_user.user_id = tbl_user_group.user_id 
  AND tbl_user_group.group_id = 11
```

Comment: You should look at the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html). There are examples (select, from, join, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (not tested):

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('tu' => 'tbl_user'),
                    array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email'))
             ->join(array('tug' => 'tbl_user_group'),
                    'tu.user_id = tug.user_id',
                    array('group_id'))
            ->where('tu.organization_id = ?', 5)
            ->where('tug.group_id = ?', 11);
```